# Determining whether a differential equation is separable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation $y' = 3y − 2x + 6xy − 1$ is separable.

The differential equation $y' = x + 2y$ is NOT separable.

I can see why the second equation is not separable, but why is the first equation separable?

Comment: To see why the first one is separable, try to factor $3y-2x+6xy-1$ by grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ChristopherToni said in his comment, we can factor the right hand side of the differential equation by noticing a common factor of $2x$ in two of the terms:

$y' = 3y - 2x + 6xy -1$

$y' = 3y +2x(-1 + 3y) - 1$

Then rearranging the terms gives:

$y' = 2x(3y - 1) + 3y - 1$

And then we can factor out a common factor of $(3y -1)$ to get:

$y' = (2x + 1)(3y -1)$

From here, it is clear that the differential equation is separable.

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem**: *A function $f(x,y)$ is separable if and only if $f(x_0,y_0)f(x,y) = f(x,y_0)f(x_0,y)$, where $(x_0,y_0)\in Dom(f)$ and $f(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$*.

**Proof**: Notice that we have to prove both conditionals:

- If $f(x,y)$ is separable then we can write it as $g(x)h(y)$. Then, let's take $(x_0,y_0) \in Dom(f)$. Then $f(x_0,y_0)f(x,y) = g(x_0)h(y_0)g(x)h(y)$. We reorganize the terms of the right hand side of the equation: $g(x)h(y_0)g(x_0)h(y) = f(x,y_0)f(x_0,y)$.
- Let $g(x)=\dfrac{f(x,y_0)}{f(x_0,y_0)}$ and $h(y)=f(x_0,y)$ be functions. Then:
  $$g(x)h(y)=\frac{f(x,y_0)f(x_0,y)}{f(x_0,y_0)}=\frac{f(x_0,y_0)f(x,y)}{f(x_0,y_0)}=f(x,y).$$

QED.

---

Now, you have to choose any $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $f(x_0,y_0)\neq0$. Then you build $g$ and $h$. **The equation is separable if and only if $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$**.

Answer (score 1):

The factorization becomes clearer when we write it as $y' = 6xy-2x + 3y - 1$. Then we obtain a differential equation

> $y' = (2x+1)(3y-1) \implies \frac{y'}{3y-1} = 2x+1$

which shows that it is separable.