# How to prove an ordinary differential equation is not separable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Some elementary exercises require one to determine whether or not an ordinary differential equation is separable. For example, it is understood that the equation $$y'=\frac{1-2xy}{x^2}$$ is not separable. An easier example is $y'=x+y$. Usually this is intuitive understandable; however, can one give a strict proof that the right hand of these equations cannot be written as a product of the form $p(y)q(x)$?

I am aware of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006680/determining-whether-a-differential-equation-is-separable), but am not sure if the method mentioned in one of the answers is a good approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, a $\mathcal{C}^2$ function $f(x,y) \neq 0$ can be expressed in the form $p(x) q(y)$ if and only if 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial x \partial y} = 0.
$$

**Proof:**  First, note that if $f(x,y) = p(x) q(y)$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{1}{f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{p(x) q'(y)}{p(x) q(y)} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{q'(y)}{q(y)} \right) = 0.
$$
To prove the converse, suppose that 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial \ln f}{\partial y} \right)= 0.
$$
If this is true, the quantity in square brackets must be a function of $y$ only:
$$
\frac{\partial \ln f}{\partial y} = g(y).
$$
We can then integrate this with respect to $y$;  if $G(y)$ is the antiderivative of $g(y)$, we must have
$$
\ln f = G(y) + h(x).
$$
(Note that we are free to add a "constant with respect to $y$", i.e., a function $h$ that depends only on $x$, to the antiderivative.)  We conclude that
$$
f(x,y) = e^{G(y) + h(x)} = p(x) q(y)
$$
where $p(x) = e^{h(x)}$ and $q(y) = e^{G(y)}$.

(I have implicitly assumed throughout that $f(x,y) > 0$, but the above proof can be easily extended to domains where $f(x,y) < 0$ as well.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to clarify one thing about the part "$\ln f$": What if $f<0$?

Comment: @Zuriel:  See my note at the bottom.  Basically, the same proof can be applied to $\ln (-f)$.

Comment: Thanks again! Is it a theorem from Calculus?

Comment: @Zuriel:  I came up with the proof on my own, but given that it didn't take terribly long, I suspect it was already known.  :-)  The techniques I used in this proof are well-known in the study of partial differential equations (PDEs).

Comment: Thank you! Do you also require that $f(x,y)\neq 0$ for all $x,y$?

Answer (score 3):

Using the approach you've linked, let $f(x,y) = \frac{1-2xy}{x^2}$. Consider $(x_0,y_0) = (1,0)$ and notice that $f(x_0,y_0) = f(1,0) = 1 \neq 0$. We now show that $f(x_0,y_0)f(x,y) \neq f(x,y_0)f(x_0,y)$ which will show that $f(x,y)$ is not separable.

Notice that,

$$f(x_0,y_0)f(x,y) = 1\cdot f(x,y) = f(x,y) = \frac{1-2xy}{x^2}$$

and

$$f(x,y_0)f(x_0,y) = f(x,0)f(1,y) =  \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1-2y}{1} = \frac{1-2y}{x^2}.$$

Since $\frac{1-2xy}{x^2}$ and $\frac{1-2y}{x^2}$ are not the same function, then we've shown that $f(x,y)$ isn't separable.